# Populate combo box using user input

Tags: javascript, acrobat

Is there a way to add a item to a combo box from a text box on the same page? Also how would you add that item to multiple combo boxes on the same page? This is an acrobat pdf form. Any examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It really depends on how you are implementing the combo box/s.  Wire up a text input to a button or any element you like.  In its click function just add the text as a new option, li or whatever elements you are using for your combo box options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible.

The best is to get the Acrobat JavaScript documentation, which is part of the Acrobat SDK, downloadable from the Adobe website. Of particular interest are the entries for setItems() and getItems() and their referenced Field object methods.

Due to the implementation of adding items, you would first read the current items, then add your new item, and then write them back (for the example, we assume that there are no specific return values):

```
var f = this.getField("myComboBox") ;
var fitms = new Array() ;

for (var fi = 0 ; fi < f.numItems ; fi++ ) {
fitms[fi] = f.getItemAt(fi, false) ;
}

if (this.getField("myAddingValue").valueAsString.length > 0) {
fitms[fitms.length] = this.getField("myAddingValue").valueAsString ;
}

f.setItems(fitms) ;
```

Add this code to a button to add the item in the field myAddingValue, and that's about it. There are code samples in the above mentioned documentation.

You might create a document-level function which takes the combo box field and the field for the add-on value as argument.

Comment: Works well, one question though.  How would I make this work for multiple combo boxes.  Lets say I have 5 combo boxes named place1,place2,place3,place4,place5

Comment: If all combo boxes should be in synch, you would use the setItems() command for each of the boxes, and instead of defining the variable f for those (subsequent) fields, access them directly with this.getField("place1").setItems(fitms) ; and so on.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery to do it.. consider this as HTML

```
<text id="mytext">
<button id="btnAdd" type="button">Add</button>
<select class="awesomecombo" id="combo_one"></select>
<select class="awesomecombo" id="combo_two"></select>
```

Javascript is

```
$("#btnAdd").click(function(){
    $(".awesomecombo").append("<option>"+$("#mytext").val()+"</option>");
});
```

This will solve your purpose.

UPDATE: added class for multiple combobox selection and `<option>` in append.

Comment: This is a very bad example.  The append would not be to just append the text, but would need to be an <option>value</option>  Also avoid ID's as your main targets for this activity.  If you have multiple you need to append to, use a class and then you can insert into all at once.

Comment: Agree with you, I totally forgot to add `<option></option>`.. and didn't consider `class` for multiple combobox. Updating answer.

Comment: Cool, you have the concept correct but based on the question its probably best to give a functional example.

Comment: I'm sorry I should have stated that this is a Acrobat form.  I tagged it, but didn't specify in my question. any examples would be a huge help.

Comment: I updated the question after @Ariful Haque gave his anwser, to be more clear.  Still need help with this? Anyone?

Comment: @JustinPetty: yeah, I realized the timing; I came to the question after the update… see my answer…